# Could not rebase - conflict - could not apply a certain pick

Tags: git

I cannot seem to get past this.  I've even re-cloned down the repo, checked out the latest remote branch to a new local branch, and no matter what every time I try to rebase I get this:

**▶ git rebase -i develop**

```
error: could not apply 51fcda4... problem with call to API - getting 403

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 51fcda43833973b36fd496c47ab9bcaa0b888a89... problem with call to API - getting 403
```

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that rebasing can result in merge conflicts as commits are replayed on top of your branch?  Just check `git status` and you should see a bunch of files in conflict.

Comment: So what is your question? You need to resolve conflicts manually.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the merge conflicts in the files and go on with `git rebase --continue`.